# Can Sophos Enterprise Console run on Windows 7?

Tags: sophos

I am looking at migrating Sophos Enterprise Console from off an old windows 2003 server onto a new host.

I have spare windows 7 licences but no server 2008 spare, does anyone know if the server part of the Sophos Enterprise Console solution can be run on a Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all components except the NAC can:
http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/endpoint/endpoint-protection/components/management-console/system-requirements.aspx